# Configuring a pico w as an access point and web server works with default ifconfig, but breaks with 172.16.x.x

Tags: pi-pico

I have a pico w that I'm setting up as an access point:

```py
ap = network.WLAN(network.AP_IF)
ap.config(essid=xxxx, password=xxxx)
ap.active(True)
```

and then I'm serving a "tell me how to connect to your router" web page:

```py
s = socket. Socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
s.listen(1)

client, _ = s.accept()
...
```

And this works just fine. I connect eg a laptop to the access point and go to `http://192.168.4.1` and the page appears. But I want to display a QR code with the `http://...` link to the web page on a 64x64 pixel matrix display that the pico is driving. So to enable me to use a 21x21 pixel QR code, I need the IP address range of pico access point to be `172.16...`, rather than the `192.168...` default. So to do that, I'm adding:

```py
ap.ifconfig(('172.16.4.1', '255.255.255.0', '172.16.4.1', '0.0.0.0'))
```

to the access point setup code. Calling `print(ap.ifconfig())` after it's configused shows it's setting up with that address range. But the website stops working. Accessing `http://172.16.4.1` doesn't work and the web server doesn't accept the connection.

As suggested by goldilocks, I checked the laptop that is connected to the access point. It has an IP address in the `192.168...` range. So it doesn't look like the pico w is either running a DHCP server, or if it is, it's assigning addresses in the wrong range.

So my questions:

1. Does the soft access point in the `network.WLAN` code that the RP2 version of MicroPython uses support a DHCP server, or is the laptop handling this due to a lack of DHCP? The laptop is not connected to any other network, just the pico w access point.
2. If the pico is supplying DHCP support, is there a way to configure the address range that it uses?

Comment: *"Accessing http://172.16.4.1 doesn't work and **the web server doesn't accept the connection.**"* -> That phrase smells like conjecture, is it?  If what literally happens is that whatever web browser you are using says, "Connection refused", this is **not** the web server, because web servers (or application level servers generally) cannot do that.  You need to clarify what actually happens alongside (or instead of) what you assume or think is happening.

Comment: The client eventually times out and the `client, _ = s.accept()` line is never reached. Not sure I can clarify further as I’ve no further information as to what’s going wrong, which is why I’m asking. 

Comment: That implies the request is not reaching the Pico at all (beyond going through the wifi AP); check to see if exactly the same thing happens when you try to connect to a non-existent node on the same subnet (eg., 172.16.4.111).  What IP is the client laptop using?

Comment: @goldilocks, checking the laptop was the key to figuring out why it's not working. The laptop is still being assigned a 192.168 range IP address. It looks like I can change the ifconfig for the pico itself, but there's no way to configure the behaviour of the DHCP server that the access point provides. Looks like my plan needs a rethink. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Suggest you read [this on usage of link-local addresses](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/link-local-address/).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose. What system is your DHCP server? The pico? A router? The DHCP server must be configured to assign addresses from a matching range.

Comment: @Bodo, edited as requested.

Comment: @DavidArno You added questions without sufficient information to answer them. I did not find any information about using a Pico as a DHCP server. Add details about your network and your use case, and the network configuration of your laptop. Maybe your router provides a DHCP server which could be configured for your case (under certain preconditions).

Comment: @Bodo, it's not attached to the router. The Pico W is the "router". That's what an access point is. The network is a pico w as the access point and a laptop attached to that access point via wifi. My use case is I want a device attached to that access point to be able to reach `http://172.16.4.1`. All of this is in the question. "*I did not find any information about using a Pico as a DHCP server*". Nor did I, which is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide information, don't use comments for this purpose. Repeating information from the question does not help. You are right that an access point is **a** router, but it might not be the only one in your network. Are you saying that your network consist *only* of the Pico and a Laptop and nothing else? No other network connection? Please clarify this in your question. You still did not provide any information about where the IP address of the Laptop comes from. Assuming the Pico cannot provide DHCP, I'm searching for other options to solve your problem.